# svn: E175013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL

Tags: ubuntu, svn

I'm trying to get xbt-tracker from googlecode.com/svn but for some reason I get the following:

```
svn co http://xbt.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/xbt/misc xbt/misc
svn: E175013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://xbt.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/xbt/misc'
svn: E175013: Access to 'http://xbt.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/xbt/misc' forbidden
```

Comment: Are you from a place using a proxy or blocking SVN, because I just try and I have been able to checkout the two repository.

Answer (score 0):

It's what happens if you come via IPv6.

You can temporarily disable it via
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1